# Yii render page with html id

Tags: php, yii

As I know render is move to another page ...

**For example:**

```
$this->render('index'); // move to index.php
```

**In normal HTML we can simply do this for what I want- For example:**

Click `index.php#tab1` will move to location `tab1` ... How bout Yii ?

I tried `$this->render('index#tab1');` but doesn't work. Any suggestion to do that ? Thanks

Comment: `render()` method will render full `views/{controller}/index.php`. I think you are talking about link, not `render` method.

Comment: @Justinas but move to the index are not clicking by link ... that link is just my example to explain what I want

Comment: @TheSmile: The `#` part of an URL can only be used on client side, so Yii isn't able to handle this...

Comment: @TheSmile If you click on link `index.php#tab1` than your **browser** will jump to that location. Yii (as PHP framework) will only output view file to user. `renderPartial()` can be used to output only single part of view, but it will not make "jump" effect.

Comment: @Justinas I see ... do u have any other suggestion to do that in yii ?

Comment: @TheSmile Not possible via Yii or any other server-side-based stuff.

Comment: It is possible with a little workaround, but not too nice. Pass it as a parameter to keep the information and in the corresponding view output some JS to simulate the required effect of #tab.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked.

```
$this->redirect(array('/site/index','#'=>'tab1'));
```

Thanks